# Handling iOS platform downgrade and Reuse of App Name

Tags: ios, app-store, universal, downgrade

I haven't been able to find relevant answer to this problem. Please redirect if you know it's a duplicate question.

**Background**:

I have this version 1.0 of an app on the App Store. It's basically a wrapper around a WebApp and the updated 2.0 version I am working on is a native implementation for iPhone.

Now the current version 1.0 of the app is Universal. So trying to submit our finished 2.0-native iPhone only app is refused by AppStore since it's considered a downgrade to no longer support iPad.

The roadmap ahead includes a future release of an iPad-version as well, and this needs to be taken into account. I believe there are good reasons for this iPad-app to be Universal. **We need** to keep the **current AppName** in some way.

Now I need advice on how to best handle the situation. These are the steps I consider:

- Release v2.0 under new appName i.e. "MyApp 2"
- Remove v1.0 app from sales, but keep it in iTunesConnect to save the name
- Change WebAppContent of v1.0 to notify the current userbase of the native app (2.0)
- When we are ready to release a Universal App we update the current 1.0 instead of 2.0 to reclaim the original name

**Questions:**

- Is there a better way?
- If we remove v1.0 from sales and release v2.0 under the name "MyApp 2", is there a way to change the later name back to "MyApp" when v1.0 is of the stores?
- If we consider deleting v1.0 completely from iTunesConnect, can we, as the same company, then reclaim the name when it becomes publicly available again (or are we blacklisted for that name)?
- Can you have different display names for an App on AppStore and on the devices home screen (how is this done)?

Comment: Why not keep the app Universal, but have the iPad idiom continue load the web app like it does now? Sure, it means having your project essentially be a union of the old and new codebases until you get around to doing the native iPad version, but no App Store shenanigans necessary.

Comment: Actually that is not a bad idea, I'm not sure I have access to the old code base though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: If you delete an app in iTunes Connect, that app's name is no longer available for use by that same Developer account ever again.

Bundle display names are independent of App store names.  Many apps have shortened or abbreviated Bundle display names to fit under the icon, and a much longer app store name.